# Storing information in a variable vs data-attribute elements

Tags: javascript, optimization

We have option1:

```
MyApp.frames.frame1 = {};
MyApp.frames.frame1.element = document.getElementById("#frame1");
MyApp.frames.frame1.alias = "f1";
MyApp.frames.frame1.otherInfo = "FOO";
```

option2:

```
<div id="frame1" data-alias="f1" data-otherinfo="FOO"></div>
```

In terms of better code practice and performance which one is better?

I find option 2 is faster since it is less code. But personally I find it easier maintaining option 1 since I can find where I use the variable but again its more code.

But aside from that I don't really know any real pros or cons with using option1 or option2. I want to be consistent in my code so any insights would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The second is quicker. But using object to configure is more maintainable.
Reasons:

1. The second is quicker: the dom is created whiling setting this attribute. It's only one turn. The first one includes dom modification, which the browser checks whether dom should be rendered or not.
2. For me, I would use following:

   ```
   MyApp.frames.frame1={
       element:document.getElementById(),
       alias:"F1",
       otherInfo:"F00"
   }
   ```

   which is more configurable and visually fine.
3. This is what you have to mention about:
   `data-*` is retrieved with `dom.dataset["attr"]`

Comment: I actually set objects that way. I just wanted to make it clear at my question that you can add properties outside of the initialization of `frame1` ;)

Comment: Add up properties...But using data- way to add properties to doms still require javascript to manipulate the dataset. I guess we need further study into the cost of manipulating `dataset` and custom attribute.

Comment: [check this out in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jose_mar/wzv47ssp/)... I wrote a page to test for both situation and find using native dataset is much quicker. Dataset is using DOMStringMap which should have been optimized i guess. ;))